# Magento getting warning in log file after removing plugin

Tags: magento-1.8, php, onestepcheckout, extensions

I have removed the one step checkout plugin from my store completely but I am still getting warning

```
include(Idev/OneStepCheckout/Model/Sales/Quote.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
```

in log file. Do I need to remove any other setting from table core_config_Data? or I am missing anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ram Sharma,

```
   Step1:clear cache using delete all file from var/cache
   step2: if you have enable compiler then disable compiler from magento admin and  clear cache again enable compiler
  Step3:if php cache enable then clear php cache
  step:Idev_OneStepCheckout is  not remove properly check it files and folder again
```

Comment: I have removed the plugin/extension properly but I have to look into php cache

Answer (score 0):

Have your cleared var/cache? Seems like your Magento installations till has the xml cache built up from which it is trying to look up the Model.